# how to load a value from textbox to dropdown in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a dropdown and textbox.some datas are loaded in the dropdown.when i select an item from the dropdown,the value saved in the textbox.but after saving the value ,item is not loaded in the dropdown.what can i do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPjv7.png)

Comment: can u please show me ur effort. ?

Comment: @Arsalan Qaiser
I need to load the value from textbox to dropdown

Comment: can u please show me ur  code

Comment: What @ArsalanQaiser means is: What have you tried thus far and what efforts have you made to attempt this operation?